# AVAssetWriter stuff leaks

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, avfoundation

hallo, i am newbie in ios development and i have endountered some problems

i do some setup of AVAssetWriter like objects (i use it to write pixelmaps
as frames to video - and it works ok)

```
    self.assetWriter = [[AVAssetWriter alloc] initWithURL:outputPath fileType:AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie error:&error];

    NSMutableDictionary *dic=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [dic setValue: AVVideoCodecH264 forKey: AVVideoCodecKey];
    [dic setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:640] forKey:AVVideoWidthKey];
    [dic setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:480] forKey:AVVideoHeightKey];
     self.assetWriterInput = [[AVAssetWriterInput alloc] initWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo outputSettings:dic];
      [dic release];

    assetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor =[[AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor alloc] initWithAssetWriterInput:assetWriterInput sourcePixelBufferAttributes:nil];

    self.assetWriterInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime=YES;
    [self.assetWriter addInput:assetWriterInput];

    [self.assetWriter startWriting];
    [self.assetWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:recordStartTime];
```

then after it i save video and then after it i release instances

```
[self.assetWriterInput markAsFinished];
[self.assetWriter endSessionAtSourceTime:recordStartTime];
[self.assetWriter finishWriting];

CVPixelBufferPoolRelease(assetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor.pixelBufferPool);
[self.assetWriter release];
[self.assetWriterInput release];
[self.assetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor release];
```

trouble is that Instruments show me leaks when i use above pair a couple of times to create and release instances to save a couple of videos

HELP!

Comment: Are the leak traces in Instruments indicating that the leak is with your code? Have you run a static analysis on your code?

Answer (score 0):

```
AVAssetWriter *newWriter = [AVAssetWriter alloc] // retain count is 1. 
self.assetWriter = newWriter // What this actually does:

- (void)setAssetWriter(AVAssetWriter*)newWriter
{
    if (_assetWriter != newWriter)
    {
        [_assetWriter release]
        _assetWriter = [newWriter retain]; //retain count 2
    }
}

[self.assetWriter release]; //retain count 1
```

If you forgot to add self.assetWriter = nil; to dealloc, you'll leak eventually. When [Alloc]ating instances and assigning them trough @properties, append autorelease to alloc line like this:

```
self.assetWriter = [[[AVAssetWriter alloc] initWithURL:outputPath fileType:AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie error:&error] autorelease];
```

Comment: those are simply an assign properties `@property (assign) AVAssetWriter * assetWriter;
@property (assign) AVAssetWriterInput * assetWriterInput;
@property (assign) AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor * assetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor;` so i think it is off question (?)